# Traverse XML nodes using vbscript

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript

I've got an XML file that I'd like to traverse and output a couple of specific attributes. This is my first time using using XML data directly but I think this should be straightforward and yet I am defeated.

A simplified version of the  XML is like this - I've removed extra attributes from this example.

I'd like to traverse down the XML reading these nodes/attributes so that my output is the same as what I have received. However currently I'm getting one header and then all the dates in a long list.
Do I need to count all the nodes and then work my way through counting and outputting each result? That seems overly complicated for this example to me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<contact_list >
  <contact >
    <enrolment description="Online Course April 14" >     
      <student_teaching_day teaching_date="16/04/14" teaching_days="1" session_from="9:01" session_to="10:01"  />
      <student_teaching_day teaching_date="24/04/14" teaching_days="1" session_from="9:02" session_to="10:02"  />
      <student_teaching_day teaching_date="01/05/14" teaching_days="1" session_from="9:03" session_to="10:03"  />
      <student_teaching_day teaching_date="08/05/14" teaching_days="1" session_from="9:03" session_to="10:03"  />
    </enrolment>
    <enrolment description="Online Course May 14" >     
      <student_teaching_day teaching_date="16/04/14" teaching_days="1" session_from="9:01" session_to="10:01"  />
      <student_teaching_day teaching_date="24/04/14" teaching_days="1" session_from="9:02" session_to="10:02"  />
      <student_teaching_day teaching_date="01/05/14" teaching_days="1" session_from="9:03" session_to="10:03"  />
      <student_teaching_day teaching_date="08/05/14" teaching_days="1" session_from="9:03" session_to="10:03"  />
    </enrolment>
    <enrolment description="Online Course June 14" >     
      <student_teaching_day teaching_date="16/04/14" teaching_days="1" session_from="9:01" session_to="10:01"  />
      <student_teaching_day teaching_date="24/04/14" teaching_days="1" session_from="9:02" session_to="10:02"  />
      <student_teaching_day teaching_date="01/05/14" teaching_days="1" session_from="9:03" session_to="10:03"  />
      <student_teaching_day teaching_date="08/05/14" teaching_days="1" session_from="9:03" session_to="10:03"  />
    </enrolment>
  </contact>
</contact_list>
```

My Script

```
For Each Node In xmlDoc.documentelement.selectNodes("//enrolment")
    If Not Node is Nothing Then
    course_description = Node.getAttribute("description")
    table_teaching_dates_start = "<table><tr><th colspan='4'><strong>"+course_description+"</strong></th></tr>"

        For Each Day In Node.selectNodes("./student_teaching_day")
                student_teaching_date = "<td>"+Day.getAttribute("teaching_date")+"</td>"
                session_from = "<td>"+Day.getAttribute("session_from")+"</td>" + "<td> - </td>"
                session_to = "<td>"+Day.getAttribute("session_to")+"</td>"

            student_dates = student_dates + "<tr>" +student_teaching_date + session_from + session_to + "</tr>"

        Next
        table_teaching_dates_end ="</table>"
        End If
Next

total = table_teaching_dates_start + table_row_start + student_dates + table_row_end + table_teaching_dates_end
```

Comment: I don't think trying to construct XML or HTML doing string concatenation is a good idea, there is XSLT to transform XML to XML or HTML. In terms of XPath doing `//enrolment` first and then `./student_teaching_day` inside looks fine however. Can you post a snippet of the output you get and show us the one you want instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main `For Each` loop keeps overwriting the variables you use the build the tables, with the exception of `student_dates`, which you keep appending to. Your loop logic is all right, your HTML building logic is not.

Maybe you should change your approach to constantly appending to *the same* output variable. The following code does that and is a little more pleasing to look at.

```vb
Dim enrolment, day, output, html

Set output = New StringBuffer

For Each enrolment In xmlDoc.selectNodes("//enrolment")
    output.Append "<table>"

    output.Append "<tr><th colspan='3'><strong>"
    output.Append HTMLEscape(enrolment.getAttribute("description"))
    output.Append "</strong></th></tr>"

    For Each day In enrolment.selectNodes("./student_teaching_day")
        output.Append "<tr>"

        output.Append "<td>"
        output.Append HTMLEscape(day.getAttribute("teaching_date"))
        output.Append "</td>"

        output.Append "<td>"
        output.Append HTMLEscape(day.getAttribute("session_from"))
        output.Append "</td>"

        output.Append "<td>"
        output.Append HTMLEscape(day.getAttribute("session_to"))
        output.Append "</td>"

        output.Append "</tr>"
    Next

    output.Append "</table>"
Next

html = output.ToString
```

With a helper class `StringBuffer`, which helps string building performance. (In VBScript, like in many other languages, string are immutable. Concatenating them a lot is slow.)

```vb
Class StringBuffer
    Dim dict

    Sub Class_Initialize
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End Sub

    Sub Append(s)
        dict.Add dict.Count, s
    End Sub

    Function ToString
        ToString = Join(dict.Items, "")
    End Function

    Sub Class_Terminate
        Set dict = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

and the obligatory HTML escape function you really should *always* use when building HTML from strings.

```vb
Function HTMLEscape(s)
   HTMLEscape = Replace( _
                Replace( _
                Replace( _
                Replace( s, _
                    "&", "&amp;"  _
                ),  "<", "&lt;"   _
                ),  ">", "&gt;"   _
                ), """", "&quot;" _
                )
End Function
```

---

PS: Note the your test `If Not Node is Nothing Then` test is unnecessary. `Node` can never be `Nothing` at this point.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I see I was pretty naive in my approach to a "simple" xml traversal!

Comment: But your XML traversal was all-right, just as I said.